# Submit button is not working in my form

Tags: php, html, css, forms

This is my form. When I click save, vales are not getting posted and redirected to note.php page.

```
<form method="post" action="note.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-1 padding">
            <label>Title :</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11 padding">
            <input type="text" class="form-control select2-offscreen form-text" name="title" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Note Heading" tabindex="-1">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="toolbar-btns">
        <div class="file-attach">
            <div class="form-group">  
                <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn send-btn" name="btn-note-save">Save</button>
            <input type="reset" style="background-color:#417fb9; color:#fff;" class="btn btn-default"  id="submitForm" value="Clear"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Hey where is your <form> start code

Comment: There is no `<form>` tag.

Comment: Sorry starting line got truncated. here it is, <form method="post" action="note.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Please include the codes in `note.php`

Comment: yes i have created note.php page and included codes. but when i click submit its not taking to not.php page itself.

Comment: No action happening when click save button

Comment: It's working fine **[See](https://plnkr.co/edit/fQafp2aVofBofR4cQzV4?p=preview)**

Comment: @viswanathan I mean add the `note.php` in the question

Comment: can you please include codes from note.php

Comment: Thank you all...its working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in note.php. Please use the code below to get the posted values.

```
<?php
$title=($_POST['title']);
echo $title;

$pic = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$folder = "../images/users/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']["tmp_name"], "$folder".$pic);
?>
```